# Saving an uploaded file - the process cannot access

Tags: c#, upload, permissions

I have the following function to handle an uploaded image.

It works fine on the first attempt (after restarting IIS), but on the second attempt I always get

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by
>   another process

Now, I do understand that somehow the file is kept open by IIS, but why does it happen if I have

```
newFile.Flush();
newFile.Close();
newFile.Dispose();
```

Here is the full function:

```
private void SaveFile(HttpPostedFile file, string path)
{
    Int32 fileLength = file.ContentLength;
    string fileName = file.FileName;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, fileLength);

    FileStream newFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

    try
    {
        newFile.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        newFile.Flush();
        newFile.Close();
        newFile.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After a few checks, I am sure there is nothing else locking the file but `w3wp.exe` which is the IIS process.

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but may solve your problem.  Have you tried using the [SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas.aspx) method on the `HttpPostedFile` instead of creating a new filestream?  I don't know why it would help, but I suspect there may be a sneaky reason the `SaveAs` method was provided...

Comment: i did try that, but with the same result.

Comment: are you disposing the HttpPostedFile object you're passing to your SaveFile function ?

Comment: @Alex - since when a virtual file needs to be disposed? O.o

Comment: @Dementic It doesn't, that's why I've asked. The framework takes care of that, and disposing it manually might in rare cases cause problems. On a side note, that `catch { }` will blossom in a plethora of issues at some point, I highly suggest to remove it (a try...finally with no catch is fine here)

Comment: @Alex - HttpPostedFile does not have a 'Dispose()' method, is nulling it ok ?

Comment: @Alex why would the     catch{}  cause problems out of interest?

Comment: @Nt swallowing exceptions is always a bad idea: they're not supposed to be worked around, they should either be handled properly or not caught at all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something else must be keeping the file open - or perhaps the second call is made (on a separate thread) before the first call has returned.

Incidentally, you would be better writing the code like this:

```
private void SaveFile(HttpPostedFile file, string path)
{
    Int32 fileLength = file.ContentLength;
    string fileName = file.FileName;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fileLength];
    file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, fileLength);

    using (FileStream newFile = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        newFile.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: This still keeps the file locked.

Comment: Yep, because it is something else holding the lock. I just wanted to point out a better way to structure this part of the code.

Comment: well, i turned off my AV, and nothing else seems to be locking the file, the exception is thrown exactly on this function... any advice on how i could find out what is locking it ?

Comment: Hmm well you could try http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896646 but it produces an awful lot of output. Also, check the name of the file. Could it be using the same name as the one used for HttpPostedFile?